# SATA HDD detected in BIOS but not in Windows 8.1

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, bios, sata

I have a 500GB hard drive that is detected by Windows  after boot when connected by USB 3.0 but when I attempt to connect it by SATA, it is not detected by Windows.

The SATA power and data cables are firmly connected and I have tried every SATA port on my motherboard. I know that it is not my motherboard because my SSD works with any of the ports. I also tried out the other ports with a different hard drive which was detected.

My SATA controller drivers have been updated to the very latest version already. I went into device manager and it is not detected in the disk drive tab. I have gone into Disk Management and the drive is not detected there either.

The HDD is consistently detected using USB 3.0 so I can confirm that the drive is in working order.
I even ran a SMART test on it and it said that it was fine when I hooked it up via USB 3.0.

I want to connect it via SATA as opposed to USB 3.0 because I would prefer my PC hardware inside of the actual PC.

That being said, I would appreciate the help that the experts over here could provide me.

Comment: Win8 is ... something else.  What do you get if using the same (physical) config with something sensible like Ubuntu or Linux Mint? [hint] It helps in general if your "topic" is a question and not [not a question]. A question implies something to resolve.  A statement/topic does not.